# How to create a ban icon from html css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a ban icon (created from html & css) over an image but I am having a hard time creating it. I have created somewhat static-looking ban icon but it seems perfect and not responsive. Can anyone please guide me on how this can be built?

What i have done so far:

```css
.ban-icon-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 20%;
}

.ban-icon-circle{
    width: 290px;
    border: 8px solid red;
    background: transparent;
    height: 290px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.ban-icon-bar{
    height: 1px;
    border: 7px solid red;
    transform: translate(-1px, -151px) rotate(50deg);
    width: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt-2 flex align-center">
   <div class="m-5 mt-16 mx-auto">
     <div class="relative">
        <img class="object-contain ban-icon-imgg" src="/img.jpg" alt="img" />
         <div class="ban-icon-container">
           <div class="ban-icon-circle">

            </div>
            <div class="ban-icon-bar">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, How you want it to be responsive?

Comment: As at the moment, i think it can be made using two divs, one for circle and one for the bar, i don't want it to disintegrate into something else as i want it to be bigger than the image but overall smaller at small resolutions.

Comment: HI @abott svg isn't working for you? Let us know what issue you are facing in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you used an attribute named className?
Change the attribute to class and also tweak the marked styles a bit.

**Method 1**

```html
<style type="text/css">
.ban-icon-container{
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 20%;
}

.ban-icon-circle{
width: 290px;
border: 8px solid red;
background: transparent;
height: 290px;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.ban-icon-bar{
    //Change the height to 0px
height: 0px;
border: 7px solid red;
transform: translate(-1px, -151px) rotate(50deg);
    //And the width to 240px
width: 240px;
}
</style>
<div class="mt-2 flex align-center">
<div class="m-5 mt-16 mx-auto">
 <div class="relative">
    <img class="object-contain ban-icon-imgg" src="jpg" alt="img" />
     <div class="ban-icon-container">
       <div class="ban-icon-circle">

        </div>
        <div class="ban-icon-bar">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2 recommended**

You can try using [Font Awesome ban icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/ban)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to create vector icon is SVG. Look at my code this way you can create any icon and this icon will behave like and image. You can scale it accordingly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ban Icon</title>
    <style>
        .ban-icon-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 20%;
        }

        .ban-icon-circle {
            width: 290px;
            border: 8px solid red;
            background: transparent;
            height: 290px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }

        .ban-icon-bar {
            border: 7px solid red;
            transform: translate(-1px, -151px) rotate(50deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mt-2 flex align-center">
        <div class="m-5 mt-16 mx-auto">
            <div class="relative">
                <img class="object-contain ban-icon-imgg" src="/img.jpg" alt="img" />
                <div class="ban-icon-container">
                    <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="101" height="101" viewBox="0 0 101 101" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                        <circle cx="51" cy="51" r="48" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
                        <line x1="17" y1="84" x2="84" y2="17" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the only code that is creating your ban icon. You can change colors and stroke width

```
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="101" height="101" viewBox="0 0 101 101" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                        <circle cx="51" cy="51" r="48" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
                        <line x1="17" y1="84" x2="84" y2="17" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
                    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.ban-icon::before,
.ban-icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 70%;
    height: 35%;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border: 10px solid red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ban-icon::before {
    top: 15%;
    right: -8px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
.ban-icon::after {
    bottom: 15%;
    left: -8px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ban-icon"></div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg">
</div>
```